# How to set the title on MKAnnotation

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

All,

Trying to determine how to show the name of locations of user searches within the annotation pin titles as they are searched, rather than having them predetermined which is easy. My current code for my search bar that users input locations into is below:

```
- (IBAction) showAddress
{
    [addressField resignFirstResponder];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location = [self addressLocation];

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta=0.2;
    span.longitudeDelta=0.2;

    region.span=span;
    region.center=location;

    [mapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [mapView regionThatFits:region];

     MapViewAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"" andCoordinate:location];
     [self.mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
}
```

I have my title information declared below:

```
@implementation AddressAnnotation
@synthesize _name;

-(id)initWithName:(NSString*)name address:(NSString*)address coordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate  {
if ((self = [super init]))
{
    _name = [name copy];
}
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)title
{
  if ([_name isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])
    return @"Unknown charge";
  else
    return _name;
}

@end
```

My understanding is I would need to replace my initWithTitle with the title variable name, but my question is what would that look like, and is that enough to display the titles of these custom searches by the user?

Thank you!!
Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to stick with your current AddressAnnotation definition then change the last two lines of showAddress to

```
 AddressAnnotation *addAnnotation = [[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithName:@"" coordinate:location];
 [self.mapView addAnnotation:addAnnotation];
```

You'll need to replace @"" with whatever you want the title to be.

However you may want to change AddressAnnotation to use `title` instead of `_name` so that a @synthsize does all the work for you. During your init function you can set title to "unknown" if you want.